# skfuzzy can not be recognized

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

I made a traffic light prototype from raspi. My source code has given an error. The erorr said

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/testing.py", line 2, in <module>
import skfuzzy as fuzz
ImportError: No module named 'skfuzzy'
```

I already checked that scikit-fuzzy has been installed on my raspi, but whenever i run, the source can not recognize that scikit-fuzzy tools.

here is my some of source code:

```
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzz
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

Curr_GtGB=40 
Curr_GtSU=46 
Curr_GtSS=26 
Curr_GtK=12 

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

redGB=16
yelGB=18
grenGB=22

redSU=40
yelSU=38
grenSU=36

redSS=33
yelSS=35
grenSS=37

redK=11
yelK=13
grenK=15

GPIO.setup(redGB, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(yelGB, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(grenGB, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(redSU, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(yelSU, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(grenSU, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(redSS, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(yelSS, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(grenSS, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(redK, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(yelK, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(grenK, GPIO.OUT)
```

Comment: How have you installed the skfuzzy?

Comment: I followed all the instructions from here:
http://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/install.html
and 
https://scikits.appspot.com/scikit-fuzzy
everytime I repeat the installation, the system always siad that it's been already installed

Answer (score 16):

For me too, there was same error coming up .

But the command below solved it (Go to command line and type) :

```
 pip install -U scikit-fuzzy
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

@ShaliniBaranwal is correct answer

For python3 
follow command

> sudo pip3 install -U scikit-fuzzy

Also as commented by @hiwansandhi follow instructions on link  pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/install.html and scikits.appspot.com/scikit-fuzzy

These are useful to install scikit-fuzzy using easy_install and pip

> sudo pip3 install -U scikit-fuzzy

This also describes how to install from source

> git clone http://github.com/scikit-fuzzy/scikit-fuzzy.git

Answer (score 1):

So what worked for me is (I use python3):

`pip uninstall scikit-fuzzy scipy numpy networkx decorator`

```
pip3 uninstall scikit-fuzzy scipy numpy networkx decorator 
pip3 install -U scikit-fuzzy
```

Then close and open again the IDE (for me it is Spyder)